# Bash Script Quit without throwing exit

Tags: bash

hey guys I've had an issue of terminating my terminal (ssh) when exit is 
thrown in a script and am hoping for a way around it, here's an example

```
# ssh name@host
$ program

    # program contents

    #!/bin/bash
    program()
    {
        exit 0
    }

exit
Connection to host closed.
# gfd =(
```

this kicks me back to my local terminal, is there a way to exit/quit without losing my session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered my own question, `return` was what I was looking for

Comment: You were `source`ing the program instead of executing it, right?